# jQuery when filling form to all required fileds (if empty) add class redBorder except filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input, field

this is my very first question here in stackoverflow, please treat with understanding.

**What i've already done**

**HTML.** My form:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label>Surname</label>
        <input type="text" class="formInput" value="" name="form[surname]">
    </div>      

    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="formInput" value="" name="form[name]">
    </div>  

    <div>
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="formInput swdt phone" value="" name="form[phone]" maxlength="16" autocomplete="off">
    </div>  

    <div>
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input type="mail" class="formInput" value="" name="form[email]">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" class="formInput" value="" name="form[city]">
    </div>                              

    <div>
        <label>Question</label>
        <textarea class="formInput w100" value="" name="form[question]" type="text"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>captcha</label><input type="text" class="captchaFld formInput" required="" name="form[verifyCode]">
    </div>                          

    <div>
        <button class="disabled" id="submit" type="submit" disabled="">send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS.** I added an array of required fileds (this is for programmers so they can add all required fileds into this array by themselves) and as long as user has not filled all the fields in array the "send" button is disabled.

```
var requiredFields = ["surname", "name", "phone", "email", "city", "verifyCode", "question"];
```

**JS.** Here is my each function which runs through all elements of the array:

```
$.each( requiredFields, function( i, l ) {
    $(".formInput[name*='form[" + l + "]']").each(function () {
      $(this).keyup(function () {
          $("#submit").prop("disabled", chkAllFields());
      });                       
   });      
});
```

**JS.** Here is my function chkAllFields() which runs again((( through all elements of the array and check if fields empty or not:

```
function chkAllFields() {
var valid = false;
$.each( requiredFields, function( i, l ) {
    $(".formInput[name*='form[" + l + "]']").each(function () {
        if (valid) {
            $("#submit").addClass('disabled');
            if ($(".formInput[name*='form[" + l + "]']").val() == '') {
                $(this).addClass('redBorder');
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('redBorder');
            }
            return valid;
        }
        else {
            $("#submit").removeClass('disabled');
            var input = $.trim($(this).val());
            valid = !input;
        }
    });
});     
return valid;
}
```

**What i need for finish**

1. I need to add "redBorder" class to all required and empty fileds (while user types) exept the field which is now filled;
2. And on "blur" method when user "unfocus" any filed all "redBorder" classes must be removed.

For now it works with mistakes (red borders are strange) and i dont know where to find the fix..

**JS Fiddle**

Here is my example of code on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xzNPh/18/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess this is the cleanest solution: http://jsfiddle.net/xzNPh/25/

Comment: It's nice but what if i need to add and remove class "disable" to the "send" button depending on filled fields such as .prop?

Comment: it will be the same procedure as the other validations.

Comment: Thanks!!! Your decision is really very short and correct! But one thing how can i change to add redborders to all fileds when i focus not keyup? I mean both of them would be correct: focus and keyup but how to combine these two methods?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xzNPh/26/

Comment: Now its only focus), is it possible to add .keyup too? Sorry for two many questions((

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xzNPh/27/ Tadaaaaaa ;)

Comment: yeah!! I knew that it should put into the function!) Thank you GuyT! :) Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: use html5 `required` attr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your `JavaScript` to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // get the validation fields
    var requiredFields = ["surname", "name", "phone", "email", "city", "verifyCode", "question"];

    // use a function because you want to use it 'onkeyup' and on 'focus'
    var validate = function(){
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
        $.each( requiredFields, function( i, l ) {  
            $(".formInput[name*='form[" + l + "]']").removeClass('redBorder');
            if ($(".formInput[name*='form[" + l + "]']").val() == ""){
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
                $(".formInput[name*='form[" + l + "]']").addClass('redBorder');
            }                               
        });
    };

    // bind the events. I use document in case of you add fields dynamically
    $(document).on('keyup', validate);
    $('input').focus(validate);
});
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xzNPh/27/

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

is this what you're looking for? => **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xzNPh/28/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var requiredFields = ["surname", "phone", "email", "city", "verifyCode", "question"];

    $.each( requiredFields, function( i, l ) {
        $(".formInput[name*="+l+"]").each(function () {
            $(this).keyup(function () {
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", chkAllFields());
            });                     
        });     

    });

    function chkAllFields() {
        $('.formInput').not(this).each(function(){
            if($.inArray($(this).attr('name'),requiredFields)>-1 && $(this).val()==''){
                $(this).addClass('redBorder');
            }
        });
        var empty=0;
        $('.formInput').each(function(){
            if($(this).val()==''){
                empty++;
            }
        });
        if(empty==0){
            $('#submit').prop('disabled',false);
        }
        else{
            $('#submit').prop('disabled',true);
        }
    }
    $('.formInput').blur(function(){
        $('.redBorder').removeClass('redBorder');
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes! But now for some reason does not work the function that makes the "send" button active if all fields filled.

Comment: enter input.. then trigger blur.. it shows the other inputs with the redborder then removes them. i doubt this is wanted behavior?

Comment: if you fill all the inputs, the send button gets activated, wasn't that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Jquery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)?

With this plugin you can easily define which fields are required and also the 
conditions/events that have to be met before submiting the form.

Check out this [example](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/) and see if it suits your project or not.

Comment: I know about this plugin but for some reason programmers do not want any validation check on the client side.. - and of course it's not good... But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not totaly sure why you went that complicated route. try this

http://jsfiddle.net/xzNPh/23/

```
var requiredFields = ["surname", "name", "phone", "email", "city", "verifyCode", "question"];


function checkStatusBtn(){
    var valid = true;

    $.each( requiredFields, function( i, l ) {
        if ($(".formInput[name*='form[" + l + "]']").val()=="") valid=false;
    });

    // prop is better but im still stuck in an old mindset :(
    if (!valid){
        $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {



    $(document).on("submit","form",function(){
        var valid = true;


        $.each( requiredFields, function( i, l ) {
            if ($(".formInput[name*='form[" + l + "]']").val()=="") valid=false;
        });
        if (valid) {
            // do your form stuff here or leave it blank to submit normaly
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })
    $(document).on("blur","input",function(){
        checkStatusBtn();
        var $this = $(this);
        var name = $this.attr("name");
        name = name.replace("form[","");
        name = name.replace("]","");

        $this.removeClass("redBorder");

        if (requiredFields.indexOf(name)!==-1){
            if ($this.val()==""){
                $this.addClass("redBorder")
            }

        }
    });
    $(document).on("keyup","input",function(){
        checkStatusBtn();

    });
    checkStatusBtn();

});
```

personaly i would add a "required" attribute to the fields that are required and just do a check that all inputs that have "required" are filled in. wouldnt use the array route. but you might have a reason for needing it